# GetConsoleCursorInfo crashes on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: c, windows, windows-console

I'm trying to print ConsoleCursorInfo on my win7 sp1.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("xp SetConsoleCursorInfo\n");
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO *CURSOR;
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(hStdout, CURSOR);
    printf("%u",CURSOR->dwSize);
}
```

I built this code successfully with vs2019 build tools, though running it always crashes. How do I fix it?

Comment: What happens if GetStdHandle returns  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Perhaps you should check for return value of GetStdHandle?

Comment: `CURSOR` points nowhere. `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO *CURSOR` -> `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursor` and `GetConsoleCursorInfo(hStdout, CURSOR)` -> `GetConsoleCursorInfo(hStdout, &cursor);`. And BTW don't use all caps identifiers.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings: ***uninitialized local variable 'CURSOR' used***

Comment: Be aware that the warning _uninitialized local variable 'FooBar' used_ is almost always an error and should be treated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

This is your corrected code with comments:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("xp SetConsoleCursorInfo\n");
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursor;  // we need a CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO and not 
                                 // a pointer to CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO

    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (GetConsoleCursorInfo(hStdout, &cursor))   // check if GetConsoleCursorInfo fails
                                   // ^ and mind the & operator here
      printf("%u",cursor.dwSize);
    else
      printf("GetConsoleCursorInfo failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```